# How to access Parent imported functions from Module

Tags: testing, elixir, metaprogramming

I'm trying to create a test helper for testing an app that uses the [**Maru Framework**](https://github.com/elixir-maru/maru). This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
defmodule App.ExtendedMaru do
  @moduledoc false

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      use Maru.Test, unquote(opts)
    end
  end

  def post_body(url, body) do
    build_conn()
    |> Plug.Conn.put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")
    |> put_body_or_params(Poison.encode! body)
    |> post(url)
  end
end
```

The issues are with the `build_conn/0` and `post/2` functions. `build_conn/0` is defined in `Maru.Test` and can thus be reached with `import Maru.Test` inside this module.

However, `post/2` is a private function [defined inside the `__using__` macro for `Maru.Test`](https://github.com/elixir-maru/maru/blob/master/lib/maru/test.ex#L88-L106). So, it is present in the module that uses this one, but it's not available to `post_body/2`. I can't just `use Maru.Test` here as I'm required to pass the opts and haven't found a way to do so.

**Is it possible to access the `post/2` function that should be defined in the module that's including this one?**

---

EDIT: How the code ended up:

```
defmodule Legacy.ExtendedMaru do
  @moduledoc """
  Adds a few extra function helpers for testing using the Maru framework. Use
  it as you would Maru.Test, ie:

    `use Legacy.ExtendedMaru, for: An.Api.Module`
  """

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      use Maru.Test, unquote(opts)
      unquote(add_post_body())
    end
  end

  defp add_post_body() do
    quote do
      @doc """
      Makes a POST request with the given body. Correctly encodes the body in the
      requested format and sets Content-Type headers.

      ## Parameters

        - url: The URL for the POST request
        - body: The body to send on the request
        - opts: For customizing function behaviour:
          - format: What format to send the body in. Defaults to 'json'.

      """
      @spec post_body(String.t, map(), keyword(String.t)) :: Plug.Conn.t
      def post_body(url, body, opts \\ []) do
        format = opts[:format] || "json"

        build_conn()
        |> add_content(body, format)
        |> post(url)
      end

      def add_content(conn, body, "json") do
        Plug.Conn.put_req_header(conn, "content-type", "application/json")
        |> put_body_or_params(Poison.encode! body)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Either move the `post_body` method inside `__using__` or make it public and call it directly or using `defdelegate` ?

Comment: @Sheharyar that _did_ work with moving the method inside `__using__`, thanks! Also managed to move the actual definitions outside of `__using__` which makes the code a bit cleaner I think. Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises from two separate things:

- The `post_body` method is private, so you can't call it outside of your `Module`.
- The `post_body` method is not in the `__using__` macro so it's not available to any of the other modules that `use` it.

**There are two simple solutions to this:**

- Move the `post_body` method inside the `__using__` macro. Once you do this, all modules that `use` it, will be able to call `post_body` except the original module.
- **(or)** Make the `post_body` method public and call [`defdelegate`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defdelegate/2) on it inside `__using__`. This way you'll be able to call it in all modules including the original one.